# need explanation on how "git push" command works

Tags: git, github

I was trying to deploy my source code onto Github.
Then, I first added the github source to remote source as follows:

```
$ git remote add origin git@github.com:user_name/foo_bar.git*
```

Then, I tried to run "git push" command to upload my source code onto my remote github account as below.

```
$ git push

Enter passphrase for key '/c/Users/mylaptop/.ssh/id_rsa':
No refs in common and none specified; doing nothing.
Perhaps you should specify a branch such as 'master'.
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
error: failed to push some refs to 'git@github.com:user_name/foo_bar.git'
```

As I learned from railstutorial.org, I know if I use "git push" for the first time, it will return an error expecting me to specify 'origin master' parameters. But for the next and later times, I can only fire up "git push", it will work gracefully for me. What is the reason for that? as I thought the command by default always refers to the branch 'master'.

Any clear explanation would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The first time you do `git push`, there is no remote branch called master on origin.

After the branch exists, you can use `git push` and it will link to the remote branch with the same name of the branch you are currently on.

Answer (score 2):

The default behavior of `git push origin` is to sent to `origin` all local branches that have the same name as a branch on `origin`.

If you type `git push` without specifying `origin`, the name of the destination repository is inferred from the remote branch tracked by the branch you are on.  So if you are on a branch `master` tracking `origin/master`, `git push` is similar to `git push origin`.

Answer (score 1):

Git repositories have this concept of "tracking". So, from git's perspective it can know that the master branch is tracking origin/master. If it sees that relationship when you do a `git push` then it says "Oh, well he's pushing from master, which tracks with origin/master. That must be where it wants it to go."

However, before your first push - git doesn't know about this relationship which means your command is (potentially) ambiguous. You can read the official documentation about this behavior in the [Git Book's Chapter on Tracking](http://book.git-scm.com/4_tracking_branches.html).

**Note:** See the comment by Jefromi below. He points out some inaccuracies in my explanation that could be important, depending on your use case.

Comment: This isn't really correct, and that passage in the Git book is a bit misleading too. (I think it's trying to simply, not give out false information, but still.) By default, `git-push` pushes to branches of the same name, completely ignoring tracking branches. If you want it to use tracking branches, you have to set `push.default` to `tracking`. In normal cases, though, everything will Just Work - all branches track branches of the same name, and you avoid accidentally pushing your personal local branches because they don't exist on the remote.

Comment: Gah, you're correct. I've been using git for about 9 months now, successfully set up two private git servers - and I still have stuff to learn. Such is life. Thanks for the comment! :)